# Finding the URL of an XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some code that does an ajax request using jQuery, and handles success and error conditions. On an error, I want to find out what the URL I called was, so I can log it. This information appears to be contained in the XMLHttpRequest.channel, but firefox is complaining about accessing this -

```
Permission denied for <http://localhost:8081> to get property XMLHttpRequest.channel
```

Any ideas how I can determine the URL associated with an XMLHttpRequest? What's the security issue getting hold of this information?  Cheers,

Colin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security issue is [cross domain XHR requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

In FF2 you used to be able to override this in `about:config`, also see [this blog](http://www.zachleat.com/web/2007/08/30/cross-domain-xhr-with-firefox/) and especially this preference:

```
user_pref("capability.policy.default.XMLHttpRequest.channel", "allAccess");
```

But that's all not possible anymore in FF3. And with a good reason.

Note that [`XMLHttpRequest.channel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIChannel) is Gecko-specific, so this wouldn't have worked in non-Gecko browsers.

Comment: Can you explain why merely knowing the URL is a security issue?

Answer (score 5):

Ok - sorry about this - an answer is here

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

specifically this code from above link -

```
$('.log').ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
  if (settings.url == 'ajax/missing.html') {
    $(this).text('Triggered ajaxError handler.');
  }
});
```

shows how to access the request url in the event of an ajax error. Doesn't explain why the XMLHttpRequest.channel object is a no go though.  Anyway, hopefully that will help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you just add it ;]

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.baseOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open; 
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async) { this._url = url; return XMLHttpRequest.prototype.baseOpen.apply(this, arguments); };
```

then you can later ask for xhr._url in your error handler.

PS: Sorry, just discovered this thread is old.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug presents this error with a trace that shows the URI used.